# Dust.js if value in array

Tags: javascript, dust.js

I have a dust.js template file to which I pass 2 arrays:

- 1 array of options for a dropdown multiple select
- 1 array of selected options

How can I select the options in the dropdown in dust.js?

Here is an example:

The data I send to the template

```
var selectOptions = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13];
var selectedValues = [3,7,9];
```

The template

```
<select multiple>
    {#selectOptions}
        <option>{.}</option>
    {/selectOptions}
</select>
```

How can I use the {selectedValues} to select those options?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another solution that would make it cleaner for your dust.js template would be to combine both list into a new list of objects.

So using your previous data example :

```
var selectOptions = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13];
var selectedValues = [3,7,9];
var options = [];
for(var i=0;i<selectOptions.length;i++){
    var item = selectOptions[i];
    // Option object containing selected value + selected info
    var option = { value : item, selected : selectedValues.indexOf(item) > -1 };
    options.push(option);
}
```

Your dust.js template will now look like this :

```
<select multiple>
{#options}
    <option {?selected}selected="true"{/selected}>{value}</option>
{/options}
</select>
```

Comment: That's more or less what I ended up doing, but isn't there a dust way of doing this instead of modifying my object?

Comment: Modifying your object makes it cleaner in dust.js else you need to do like Simon proposed but it also means iterating on the list for every item. Dust.js is a templating engine that favor minimum code "tricks" inside the template therefore JS code is to be favored in this case.

Answer (score 6):

Add in another loop to go over your selected options

```
<select multiple>
    {#selectOptions}
        <option
            {#selectedValues val=.}
                {@eq key="{val}" value="{.}"}selected="true"{/eq}
            {/selectedValues}
        >{.}</option>
    {/selectOptions}
</select>
```

Note that I'm using the Dust Helpers from Linkedin to provide the equality comparison.

Comment: Sounds like a good solution, going to try it out now. Can't believe it didn't come to me before :)

Comment: humm...doesn't seem to be working. The double nesting is giving me the same value. ie {val} and {.} are the exact same. Any ideas?

Comment: My bad, you don't need the curly braces in the inline parameter declaration. I've edited the template. So instead of `val={.}` just use `val=.`

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely related to this concrete question, but may be useful to someone. You can create a global helper that does just that:

```
_.extend dust.helpers,

  contains: (chunk, context, bodies, params) ->
    if _.contains params.array, params.key
      chunk = bodies.block(chunk, context)

    chunk
```

I used CoffeeScript and Underscore.js but it's easily translatable to plain Javascript.

Usage:

```
// options = ["foo", "bar"]
{@contains array=options key="bar"}
  Bar is an option.
{/contains}
```

There is also a plugin, much more extensive, with the same functionality in [dustjs-helpers-extra](https://github.com/nikolaygit/dustjs-helpers-extra).

More info on how to [create global helpers](http://www.dustjs.com/guides/dust-helpers/#adding-new-helpers).