# Dust helper equal for select control

Tags: html, dust.js, dust-helpers

I have this template i need select proper selected option, how to compare it with dust helpers? https://stackoverflow.com/a/19628029/880709 didn't work for me

```
{#data.PRODUCT_TURNOVER_DATA}
<tr>
    <td><input name="ID_TYPE_TURN" value='{.ID_TYPE_TURN}'></td>
    <td>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <select class="form-control" name="ID_TYPE_TURN">
                            {#data.SPR_TYPE_TURN_DATA}
                                <option value="{.ID_TYPE_TURN}" selected='?'>{.NAME_TYPE_TURN}</option>
                            {/data.SPR_TYPE_TURN_DATA}
                            </select>
                        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
{/data.PRODUCT_TURNOVER_DATA}
```

Data:

```
"data": {
      "PRODUCT_TURNOVER_DATA": [
        {
          "ID_PRODUCT_TURNOVER": 4,
          "DATE_TURN": "2015-12-29T21:00:00.000Z",
          "ID_TYPE_TURN": 2,

        }
      ],
     "SPR_TYPE_TURN_DATA": [
        {
          "ID_TYPE_TURN": 1,
          "NAME_TYPE_TURN": "Передано в составе УТАС",
          "ACC_OPT": 1
        },
        {
          "ID_TYPE_TURN": 2,
          "NAME_TYPE_TURN": "Получено от контрагента для ревизии",
          "ACC_OPT": -1
        }]
```

Criteria of equality

```
PRODUCT_TURNOVER_DATA.ID_TYPE_TURN == SPR_TYPE_TURN_DATA.ID_TYPE_TURN
```

Comment: What is the criterion for deciding whether or not the item is selected?

Comment: PRODUCT_TURNOVER_DATA.ID_TYPE_TURN == SPR_TYPE_TURN_DATA.ID_TYPE_TURN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `{@eq}` helper to compare these two values.

```
<option value="{.ID_TYPE_TURN}" {@eq key=PRODUCT_TURNOVER_DATA[0].ID_TYPE_TURN value=.ID_TYPE_TURN}selected='selected'{/eq}>{.NAME_TYPE_TURN}</option>
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot. Any idea how to solve this? http://stackoverflow.com/q/34638580/880709