# Function call and checking results in DustJs

Tags: dust.js, dust-helpers

I am combining connect-roles with dust template
ejs template have something like this syntax

```
<% if (userCan('impersonate')) { %>
  <button id="impersonate">Impersonate</button>
<% } %>
```

and that in jade

```
if userCan('impersonate')
  button#impersonate Impersonate
```

How to do this in dust?

```
            {@eq key=userCan('edit data') value="true" }
                <td><a href='/assets/edit/{.ID_ASSET}'>Edit</a></td>
                <td><a href='/assets/delete/{.ID_ASSET}'>Delete</a></td>
            {:else}

            {/eq}
```

This code get me an error

```
Wed, 06 Jan 2016 16:57:47 GMT uncaughtException Expected end tag for assets but it was not found. At line : 42, column : 13
```

---

Edit:
I have this in `{@contextDump key="full"/}`

```
   "tail": {},
  "isObject": true,
  "head": {
    "enrouten": {
      "routes": {},
      "path": "function path(name, data) {var route;route = this.routes[name];if (typeof route === 'string') {return path2regexp.compile(route)(data);}return undefined;}"
    },
    "userIs": "function (action) {var act = ert(req, action);return roles.test(req, act)}",
    "userCan": "function (action) {var act = ert(req, action);return roles.test(req, act)}",
    "isAuthenticated": "function () { [native code] }",
    "_csrf": "FSaqN0PWxOF4slTUfnGHXJ0NkPOTJFl0u57eM=",
    "title": "Справочник спецификаций",
    "assets": [
      {
        "ID_ASSET": 1,
        "SYMBOL_KODE": "12.TR.18",
        "DOK_NAME": "ТХ9042",
        "DESCRIPTION": "Контроллер программируемый ТХ9042",
        "DATE_RELISE": "2001-10-04T21:00:00.000Z",
        "POS_KODE": "pos kode 1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     ",
```

And this is my controller

```
    router.get('/',  function (req, res) {
   var context = {
   req: req, // from Express callback
   userCan: function(chunk, context, bodies, params) {
     var permission = context.resolve(params.permission);
     return context.get('req').userCan(permission);
   }
 }
    models.SPR_ASSET.findAll({
      include: [ models.SPR_TYPE_UM, models.SPR_TYPE_ASSETS,  models.SPR_ASSETS_DS ]
    }).then(function(assets) {
      res.render('assets', {
        title: 'Справочник спецификаций',
        assets: assets
        context: context
      });
    });
```

`var context` here didn't work

Answer (score 4):

Dust doesn't know what functions are. It only knows about "references", which are keys in your context.

If a key in your context is a function, Dust will invoke the function and use the result in its rendering. Such functions are called **context helpers**, and you can read about them [in the documentation](http://www.dustjs.com/guides/context-helpers). Alternatively, you can register functions directly with Dust that are accessible anywhere-- these are referred to as **global helpers**.

If `userCan` is some sort of global that connect-roles makes available, you might make use of it in a global helper like this:

```
dust.helpers.userCan = function(chunk, context, bodies, params) {
  var permission = context.resolve(params.permission);
  return userCan(permission);
}
```

And in your template:

```
{@userCan permission="edit data"}
  <td><a href='/assets/edit/{.ID_ASSET}'>Edit</a></td>
  <td><a href='/assets/delete/{.ID_ASSET}'>Delete</a></td>
{:else}
  Please log in.
{/userCan}
```

---

Edit: It looks like `userCan` is request-scoped, so you can use it by adding the request variable to your context. Something like:

```
var context = {
  req: req, // from Express callback
  userCan: function(chunk, context, bodies, params) {
    var permission = context.resolve(params.permission);
    return context.get('req').userCan(permission);
  }
}

{#userCan permission="edit data"}
  <td><a href='/assets/edit/{.ID_ASSET}'>Edit</a></td>
  <td><a href='/assets/delete/{.ID_ASSET}'>Delete</a></td>
{:else}
  Please log in.
{/userCan}
```

To be clear, there is **no** method to invoke a function directly in your template in Dust-- it does not support arbitrary JS execution. To invoke a function with parameters, you must provide a helper that invokes the function so that it can transform the params into the format that your function expects.

Comment: I have userCan func in my req object in controller but i didn't see it in any parameter in dust helper, simply i can't call req.userCan("something") from dust template

Comment: If `userCan` is request-scoped, you'll need to write a context helper instead and pass the request object into your context.

Comment: this var context should be in router?  and pass it to view? then(function(assets) {
      res.render('assets', {
        title: 'Title',
        context: context
      });
    }); It didn't work that way. And i can't get req in view

Comment: i updated my question with {@contextDump key="full"/}

Comment: Don't pass `context: context`-- `context` just refers to the object you use to render with. Just add `req` into that object. You should consider reading the Dust and Express documentation.

Comment: well its seems to be confusing for me, after edit you wrote #userCan, with # sign, and i already have  "userCan": "function (action)" in my contextDump, why i need pass req via context? and i don't know how

Comment: You can't invoke functions (or execute Javascript) inside a Dust template. You can only ask Dust to render keys in its context. When Dust finds a key that is a function, it will execute the function and operate on the result, but if you want to pass params to the function it needs to be in Dust's special format, called a "helper". The documentation linked above explains how helpers work and how to write them.